# no such file to load -- capybara/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, capybara

i'm trying out the OSS [catarse](http://www.tuxtilt.com/catarse-plataforma-de-crowdfunding-open-source/) and it works fine on my machine after following the tutorial(see the link).

Then i push it to heroku using

```
git push heroku master
```

And it works fine, the problem is when i try to migrate the db using

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

I get

```
(in /app)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- capybara/rails
```

And i'm not sure what should i do, i saw a couple of solutions online, but the people that had this same problem never got an answer on the forums they post.
One of the answers was:

> I've moved capybara outside the groups and now rake db:migrate works
>   just fine, tks!!

I must say this person had a terrible english, i'm not sure what he did, buts thats pretty much all he says.
I thought he meant the Gemfile line

> group :test, :development do

Found on the original file, i removed it and the problem remains.
Any other ideas? any help would be appreciated, i'm just starting to learn rails and i'm much willing to learn anything i need to solve this issue so feel free to send me rtfm just tell me which :P

Answer (score 0):

I found that what he meant was moving the line above 
group :test, :development do
Just for clarification this is how it looked before

```
 33 group :test, :development do
 34   gem 'capybara', ">= 0.4.0"
```

Those are the line numbers btw and this is after

```
 33 gem 'capybara', ">= 0.4.0"
 34 group :test, :development do
```

Now heroku rake db:migrate works as expected, the app still doesnt work but thats for another question maybe.
If anyone care to explain that would be much appreciated.